# WordPress admin media upload permission

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I have a access to the server where many wordpress blogs are hosted. Initially the permission to uploads folder were set to 777(Recursively) but this caused problems to our server and malicious files where uploaded due to which our server is blacklisted.

I have deleted all those PHP files under uploads folder and set the permission to 755.

Now the problem is that the admin users to wordpress blogs/sites unable to upload media files.

Please guide me what I can do so that they can upload files (images or videos).

Can we set something which will ask FTP details when they upload files using wordpress admin. I can create FTP users for this.

Please Guide.

Comment: What error it return when you try to upload the image from wp-admin?

Comment: ya its a simple permission issue error and when I give uploads to 777 this will be fixed but I dont want to give 777 permission. So seekiing any way so that my users can able to upload media files

Comment: Are you talking about media upload functionality from wp-admin right?

Comment: Yeah! Wordpress admin MEdia uploads

Comment: well, you can't upload files without the write permission. You will always have the risk of having malicious files uploaded, there is nothing you can do against it but basic security measures and regular maintainance.

Comment: Wordpress never says 777 permission. No directories should ever be given 777, even upload directories. Since the php process is running as the owner of the files, it gets the owners permissions and can write to even a 755 directory.

Comment: That is correct. But the permissions are not the only relevant flags, it's also relevant which user and group the directory belongs to (and what user and group the webserver is running under and belongs to). But that doesn't change the fact: The webserver needs write access. If anything running on the webserver is compromised it can be used to write in that directory.

Comment: Is there any way if the WordpRess Media Uploads ask for FTP access everytime a new file needs uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of error you are getting. But you can try this

add this line to

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads');
```

> wp-config.php

just before below line

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
```

If the directory doesn’t already exist, WordPress will automatically create it as long as the wp-content folder is writeable.

Comment: The Folder WRITE Permission is the actual issue. I DO NOT Want to give 777 permission. How to accomplish this. OR can wordpress ask FTP access to uploads MEDIA files? IF so then how? Please guide

Comment: Some server environments require you to use 777 permissions for PHP to have write access. This is not secure in a shared hosting environment. You can change your permissions to 777 temporarily to see if that allows you to upload photos but MAKE SURE YOU CHANGE THEM BACK TO 755 WHEN YOUR DONE.

Comment: Yeah 777 allows to upload stuffs but this also caused our server compromised . that is why I removed 777 permission and restored back to 755.Is there any way if the WordpRess Media Uploads ask for FTP access everytime a new file needs uploads?

Comment: Yep. Let me give a try :)

Comment: If this plugins work then I have to add this plugin to every blog/site hosted on our server. This is a big pain :(

Comment: Nop ! This is not the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just set the Permission to `chmod -v 747 uploads` and it worked. Atleast better than 777.

But would like to here suggestion if this is risky. If risky then how much. I am new to permissions and server management.

Thanks !

Comment: congratulations. you gave write permission to everyone and everything on the server.

Comment: You might want to learn how unix permissions actually work: http://www.tech-faq.com/unix-file-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for the link ! "you gave write permission to everyone and everything on the server" OMG am scared again :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I found it high in the results for an unrelated issue I am having. It seemed by the permission modes being used @vanurag was actually having a user/group permissions issue rather than the permission modes (755 vs 777) issue.

You can find the web server user with `var_dump(whoami())` in php, could be something like www-data.

Once know the user name verify that user is either the owner of the folder or is in the group assigned to the folder. You can use the following in Linux console to find current user/group.
`ls -l /path/to/wp-content/uploads`

Either add the web server user (www-data) as the owner and leave the group as it is or add the user to the group who have permissions.

Use `chown` (change owner) to set your users to your needs.

I usually add the user to the group rather than change the owner since the owner could be an FTP user and may mess up permissions used else where in your configuration.

`usermod -g www-data foobar` where foobar is the name of the group who has permissions to the uploads folder.

Here is a decent article on this issue in respect to WordPress uploads folder.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory